# Apache Mahout integration with Apache HIve

Tags: hadoop, hive, mahout

I have stored my data sets in Apache Hive but would like to use Mahout on the data in the Hive database.

How can I integrate Mahout and Hive so that I can make Mahout read from the Hive database?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the modify the mahout job and substituted the data source from hive. I do when data was stored in HBase.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you can use [HiveJDBC driver](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hivejdbcinterface.html) and on Mahout's side use corresponding JDBC component